# (Neo4j.rb) Each call of on properties of a node triggers a query to the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j.rb

Here's the problem

[A query is trigger every time when a node property is called in the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YWjp.png)

[How it looks in the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBB3z.png)

But even when a query was done to retrieve all the nodes it still sends one query for each property. Is there something that I overlooked in retrieving the nodes or there is a design flaw in the way I programmed the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of the `neo4j` gem are you using?  The latest versions should address this.

The new gems don't introduce many breaking changes (see the [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)), but if, for some reason, you can't upgrade you can set the following configuration in `config/application.rb`:

```
config.neo4j._active_record_destroyed_behavior = true
```

Comment: Seem I have been using previous version of the gem. After updating the Gemfile to specify the latest release version it's running smoothly. Thank you.